# Send nft on the shimmer network

Tags: transaction, shimmer, nft

I can't find any docs about more details than.
https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/iota.rs/how_tos/build_nft_output/#expected-output

I was looking for something like this:
https://explorer.shimmer.network/shimmer/transaction/0x69793f7d48ab8f96e05e66495f606a708ad0b71a6064f82d78a5db8061e20231
where I have to set all these parameters:

```
{
  "standard": "IRC27",
  "version": "v1.0",
  "type": "video/mp4",
  "uri": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmPoYcVm9fx47YXNTkhpMEYSxCD3Bqh7PJYr7eo5YjLgiT",
  "name": "Shimmer OG NFT #304",
  "description": "The Shimmer OG NFT celebrates the official launch of the Shimmer Network on the 28th September 2022.",
  "issuerName": "IOTA Foundation",
  "collectionId": "0xf8757e1cc7ed608efe7d2cc3fa1ea78f44015c5e56d15424516ca9349a2bdfae",
  "collectionName": "Shimmer OG NFT Collection"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats just additional metadata following the IRC27 standard.
You can read more about the standards for NFTs and Foundry Outputs here:

https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/tips/tips/TIP-0027/
https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/tips/tips/TIP-0030/

In python it would look like this:

```
nft_output = client.build_nft_output(
unlock_conditions=[
    {
        "type": 0,
        "address": {
            "type": 0,
            "pubKeyHash": client.bech32_to_hex("rms1qzpf0tzpf8yqej5zyhjl9k3km7y6j0xjnxxh7m2g3jtj2z5grej67sl6l46"),
        },
    },
],
# Nft Id needs to be set to 0 when minting
nft_id="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
amount='1000000',
immutable_features=[
    {
        "type": 2,
        # IRC27 metadata hex encoded
        "data": "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"
    }
]
```

)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how I mint a NFT collection in Python

```
import os
import json
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from iota_wallet import IotaWallet
import random

load_dotenv()

shimmer_mnemonic = os.getenv("SHIMMER_MNEMONIC")
stronghold_password = os.getenv("STRONGHOLD_PASSWORD")
wallet_db_name = os.getenv("WALLET_DB_NAME")
shimmer_account_name = os.getenv("SHIMMER_ACCOUNT_NAME")
stronghold_db_name = os.getenv("STRONGHOLD_DB_NAME")

# In this example we will mint an nft
client_options = {
    'nodes': ['https://api.testnet.shimmer.network'],
}
wallet = IotaWallet(wallet_db_name, client_options)

account = wallet.get_account(shimmer_account_name)

# Sync account with the node
response = account.sync()
print(f'Synced: {response}')

wallet.set_stronghold_password(stronghold_password)

nft_collection_size = 30  # 10 NFTs in the collection
issuer_nft_id = "rms1zpzck5vsgzlc8snf3w20z852sntyq3uxed80l46afnsj5zulms3fu4837s2"
# Create the metadata with another index for each
nft_options = []
for index in range(nft_collection_size):
    nft_number = index + 1
    attribue_value = random.randint(42, 69)
    immutable_metadata = bytes(json.dumps({
        "standard": "IRC27",
        "version": "v1.0",
        "type": "image/png",
        "uri": "ipfs://bafybeicnznoiprv5udy36wlrhqffa7evyaodewea343dnavgt3aqn4gwbm",
        "name": f"Mudskipper #{nft_number}",
        "description": "The Mudskipper",
        "issuerName": "The Queen",
        "collectionName": "The 30y old virgin collection",
        "attributes": [
            {
            "trait_type": "Rarity",
            "value": f"{attribue_value}"
            }
        ]
    }).encode('utf-8')).hex()


    print(f"immutableMetadata: {immutable_metadata}")


    combined_metadata = "0x" + immutable_metadata

    nft_options.append({
    "immutableMetadata": combined_metadata,
    "issuer": issuer_nft_id,
    })
    print(f'NFT Options: {nft_options}')


for nfts in [nft_options[i:i+50] for i in range(0, len(nft_options), 50)]:
    transaction = account.mint_nfts(nft_options)


print(f'Sent transaction: {transaction}')
```

You can see specifically how the metadata is built here

```
# Create the metadata with another index for each
nft_options = []
for index in range(nft_collection_size):
    nft_number = index + 1
    attribue_value = random.randint(42, 69)
    immutable_metadata = bytes(json.dumps({
        "standard": "IRC27",
        "version": "v1.0",
        "type": "image/png",
        "uri": "ipfs://bafybeicnznoiprv5udy36wlrhqffa7evyaodewea343dnavgt3aqn4gwbm",
        "name": f"Mudskipper #{nft_number}",
        "description": "The Mudskipper",
        "issuerName": "The Queen",
        "collectionName": "The 30y old virgin collection",
        "attributes": [
            {
            "trait_type": "Rarity",
            "value": f"{attribue_value}"
            }
        ]
    }).encode('utf-8')).hex()
```